# why does xampp not come with xdebug?

Tags: xampp, xdebug

xdebug is widely used by developers and since xampp is meant to be used in development environment i wonder why it doesnt come with xdebug installed?

so annoying to have to do it manually all the time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not really an answerable question and even with an answer does nto add anything to the global knowledge base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, some people might prefer the Zend debugger.

For another, XAMPP is a free product; the maintainers aren't getting paid for their work, so features aren't driven by user desires.  If you want the feature, request it or (better yet) offer to add it. This is basically the same as the answer to "Why doesn't open source project X have feature Y?"

Comment: i meant development but said production:) it would be great if they could include it and let you chose. people always have to do things manually. i really dont get it :(